# Sinon spy and mailgun: Attempted to wrap undefined property 'messages' as function

Tags: typescript, sinon, mailgun, sinon-chai

I am trying to test MailGun send method with Sinon, I got an error when I call

```
sandbox.spy(sender, "messages");
```

The error message is: *TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property message as function*

See the code below, not sure where is my mistake.

```
import * as sinon from 'sinon';
import * as mailgun from 'mailgun-js';
import { EmailgunService } from './emailgun.service';

let sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
const mailgunSendSpy = sandbox.stub().yields(null, { message: 'hello', id: '100' });

describe('sendEmail method', () => {
    let sender: any;
    beforeEach(() => {
        sender = sandbox.stub(mailgun.default({ apiKey: 'foo', domain: 'bar' }), 'messages')
        .returns({
            send: mailgunSendSpy,
        });
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        sandbox.restore();
    });

    it.only('should call send', async () => {
        sandbox.spy(sender, "messages");
        const emailgunService: EmailgunService = new EmailgunService();
        const result = await emailgunService.sendEmail('test@test.com','test','Hello!');
 
    });
});
```

I am using mailgun-js 0.22.0 and sinon 9.2.2

Comment: Are you using an older version of mailgun-js?

Comment: Show the code under test

Comment: I am using mailgun-js 0.22.0 and sinon 9.2.2